# Flatten nested HTML DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Given a HTML fragment like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Hello 2</h3>
</div>
```

I would like to "flatten" this to:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>Hello world</p>
<h3>Hello 2</h3>
```

How can I do that with Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Try `$("body > * *").appendTo("body")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.body.children.length; i++) {
    var e = document.body.children[i];
    for (var child of e.children) {
        document.body.appendChild(child);
    }
```

}

Because `document.body.children` is a "live" collection, it changes as you append items to the body, so your body itself will serve as the queue for the elements to be processed in a lateral traversal.

(I'm mixing loop types because I'm not 100% sure iterators work the same way with live collections, and I'm not at a computer to check. If I or someone can confirm that `for (var e of document.body.children)` works the same way, I'll update the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "**Live Selector"** `document.body.children`

Here is the `ES6` snippet

```
for (const e of document.body.children) {
    for (const child of e.children) {
        document.body.appendChild(child);
    }
}
```