# Unnest nested tags in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Take for exepmple this html:

```
<tag>sometext<tag>sometext</tag>sometext</tag>
```

i want a javascript function that can replace that with:

```
<tag>sometext</tag><tag>sometext</tag><tag>sometext</tag>
```

How do i do that ?

I tried to do that using regex, but that dosent replace every nested tag and i dont know if there is an expression that can achieve that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script>
        function Unnest() {
                document.getElementById("Nested").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Nested").innerHTML.replace(/<tag>(.*?)<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g, '<tag>$1</tag><tag>$2</tag><tag>$3</tag>');
            }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Nested">
      <tag>sometext<tag>sometext</tag>sometext</tag>
    </div>
    <button onclick="Unnest()">Unnest</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answers your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915184/dynamically-add-missing-tags-to-a-broken-html-string

Comment: @Peterrabbit No, there are no broken tags here. The original HTML string is valid (ignoring the use of a nonexistent tag).

Comment: Then maybe this can be an answer to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967843/flatten-nested-html-dom-nodes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915184/dynamically-add-missing-tags-to-a-broken-html-string the output using the code in that link is: <tag>sometext<tag>sometext</tag>sometext</tag> (nothing changes), the code from the other link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967843/flatten-nested-html-dom-nodes outputs: <tag>sometextsometext</tag><tag>sometext</tag> (which is not what i wanted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example of a possible path to pursue depending upon the complexity of your real HTML tags and, as such, may be an oversimplification of the problem. For example, if there are many of these tag trees in your DOM with varying numbers of child nodes, then you'll have to be able to select the outer most tag of each selection; and if they are nested within each other, then you'll have to find a way select them or iterate through their child nodes, perhaps recursively. Hard to tell without more information.

Nonetheless, if you know enough about the DOM structure you're targeting you could try this kind of approach and tailor it to fit.

However, if you're attempting to handle a more general scenario or must work on the HTML as a string rather than using the DOM, then another approach that parses the string would likely be necessary.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('tag').firstChild,
    html = new Array();
    
while (el) {
  switch (el.nodeName) {
     case "TAG" :
       html.push("<tag>" + el.textContent + "</tag>");
       break;
     case "#text" :
       html.push("<tag>" + el.nodeValue + "</tag>");
       break;
     default :
       console.log("Unexpected input");
  }
  el = el.nextSibling;
}

console.log( html.join(''));
```

```html
<tag>sometext1<tag>sometext2</tag>sometext3</tag>
```

```js
    let tag = document.querySelector('tag'),
        el = tag.firstChild,
        frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        
    while (el) {
      switch (el.nodeName) {
         case "TAG" : {           
           let t = document.createElement('TAG');
           t.classList.add('indiv');
           t.textContent = el.textContent;
           frag.appendChild(t);
           break;
         } 
         case "#text" : {
           let t = document.createElement('TAG');
           t.classList.add('indiv');
           t.textContent = el.nodeValue;
           frag.appendChild(t);           
           break;
         }
         default :
           console.log("Unexpected input");
      }
      el = el.nextSibling;
    }

tag.parentNode.replaceChild(frag,tag);
```

```css
tag.indiv {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<tag>sometext1<tag>sometext2</tag>sometext3</tag>
```

Comment: @Massy I should've added that the string was written to the console for illustration only,. You may want to use a DOM method to replace the node altogether after using this approach to build the new tree, such as `document.createElement('TAG')` and setting its `textContent` within each `case` of the `switch`. You can append those to a document fragment and then replace the existing node with the newly built fragment. The point being that you don't have to use `innerHTML`. Or you could try `insertAdjacentHTML` or `insertAdjacentElement`.

Comment: @Massy An additional snippet example regarding the above comment has been added to the example answer.